# how to choose and load a file with any extension at runtime in unity

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in unity that requires some files to be stored in the database. To begin with , when the game is running , the user clicks on a button , it opens the file chooser , user chooses and it stored in db. How can I do this in unity during run time ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks
Ps : files could be .fbx, .obj or even .txt , .lbr etc..

Comment: The platform is windows I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Using the bearbone System.IO wont work for Unity simply because once compiled the game wont retain its editor way of having actual folders it will all be compiled into one file.

It will work in the editor though in play mode you will be able to use it and the only way of it to be useful would be to make tools for the editor, but for this particular case you should consider AssetsBundle more on that [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/479-using-streaming-assets-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make and fill your own directory browser.
For this you can use System.IO.

You need to follow 4 steps:

```
protected string[] m_files;
protected string[] m_folders;
```

1.- Set your path:

```
CurrentDirectory = path;
```

2.- Read files in path:

```
m_files = Directory.GetFiles(CurrentDirectory, "*.myExtension");
```

3.- Read folders in path:

```
m_folders = Directory.GetDirectories(CurrentDirectory);
```

4.- Make your browser adding file & folder icons with your customs gameobjects, extracting filenames and foldernames from m_files and m_folders arrays.

```
private string GetFolderName(string file)
{

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(file);

string shortname = info.Name;

return shortname;
}

private string GetFileName(string file)
{
string shortname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

return shortname;
}
```

To navigate to another folder you need to set an action to a directory icon elements and change path and read again files and directories.